# How to remove spaces and beginning 0 from a contact number in Views PHP view?

Tags: views

I have tried multiple variations and I cannot get this right. I have a contact number field that is user input; therefore, I need to clean it up so that I can use it in a `tel:` link on mobile devices.

Users could add numbers using different formats, such as:

- 021 457 7890
- +27 21 567 7089
- 0214577898

What I want to do (using Views PHP) is to strip the spaces, +27, and 0 at the beginning. My PHP skills are limited, but the confusing part for me is the Value code input and the Output code input and getting this to output correctly.

Note: if there is a non-Views PHP workaround, that would be preferred.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide separate fields for country code, local area code and contact number? This will let you reduce the confusion and you can use these fields in view easily.

Comment: besides the spaces, you want to remove the +27 and 0, if it starts with a zero?

Comment: What are you expecting as answer, the PHP code necessary to take off the eventual plus sign at the beginning of the number and the 0?

Comment: @RDP it's user entered so can't seperate.

Comment: @No Sssweat, yes as I need a uniform number.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, the end result needs to be 213456789 so yes if the php code is available it would be amazing.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, if there is a non-php views drupal workaround, that would be preferred. Thanks

Comment: @RickHarington there is, you need to use template files.

Comment: I re-opened the question, since the given answer suggests using a template file.

Comment: @kiamlaluno YAY!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the PHP function [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/function.str-replace.php)

```
$number = $row->field_contact_number;
// Remove the spaces.
$number = str_replace(' ', '', $number);
// Grab the first number. 
$first_number = substr($number, 0, 1); 
if ($first_number == 0) {
  // Check if the first number is 0.
  // Get rid of the first number.
  $number = substr($number, 1, 999); 
}
// Remove the + sign.
$number = str_replace('+', '', $number);
echo $number;
```

---

Although the question asked using Views PHP, it is not a good idea to enable the Views PHP and PHP Filter module. In Drupal 7, the alternative/preferred method would be to add the following code to the bottom of your **template.php** file (located in `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder).

```
function themename_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){
  if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1") {
    $number = $vars['fields']['field_contact_number']->content;
    // Remove the spaces.
    $number = str_replace(' ', '', $number);
    // Grab the first number. 
    $first_number = substr($number, 0, 1);
    if ($first_number == 0) {
      // Check if the first number is 0.
      // Get rid of the first number.
      $number = substr($number, 1, 999);
    }
    // Remove the + sign.
    $number = str_replace('+', '', $number);
    $vars['fields']['field_contact_number']->content = $number;
  }
}
```

- Replace **themename** with your theme name
- Replace **view_name** with your view name
- Replace **block_1** with your [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDJ1q.jpg)

**Remember to flush the cache to see the changes.**

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Would this just go in the Output code input? My field variable is $row->field_contact_number

Comment: @RickHarington I haven't used Views PHP in a long while. Should go on the 2nd (last box) if my memory is correct.

Comment: you're a genius!!! Thank you so much. That worked perfectly.

Comment: @RickHarington updated my answer, with alternative/preferred method.

Comment: You left a `echo $number;` inside the preprocess hook. Check the code as I edited it is the correct one.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thx for formatting it, and yeah no need to echo there, looks good.